# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Was expecting to find transaction set on current strand

Tags: corda

In Corda, I am running flow tests using a `MockNetwork`. I am trying to retrieve a transaction from one of the nodes' transaction storage using:

```
node.services.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(signedTx.id)
```

However, this is throwing the following exception:

> com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Was expecting to find transaction set
>   on current strand: Thread[main,5,main]

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you need to access a `MockNode`'s database, you need to do so inside a database transaction:

```
node.transaction {
    node.services.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(signedTx.id)
}
```