# Getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException:Was expecting to find transaction set on current strand" while running nodes from terminal

Tags: jpa, corda

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279358/java-lang-illegalstateexception-was-expecting-to-find-transaction-set-on-curren) on stackoverflow, but in my case I run the nodes from console: `deployNodes`, `runnodes`. So there is no `StartedMockNode` class to use `transaction{}` function

What’s wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Here is the method throwing the exception

```
serviceHub.withEntityManager {
    persist(callbackData)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugged this through with Hayk on Slack.

DB transactions are handled by corda. These transactions are only generated at two points. During node startup so corda services can invoke database queries and inserts and inside of flows.

In this scenario, the database was being accessed from outside of node startup and a not during a flow's invocation.

To circumvent this, a new flow needs to be created that handles the db operations that were causing the error. The db operation can still be kept inside of a corda service but it **must** be called from a flow.

This flow does not need a responder. It should be annotated with `@StartableByService` and should not need `@InitiatingFlow` (need to double check that one). The contents of `call` simply call the db operation and return the result back to the caller.

TLDR - all db operations must be called from inside a flow or during node startup.